# How do I override x-frame-options for entire Plone 5 site?

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

How do I change the "x-frame-options SAMEORIGIN" in Plone 5?  It is now being set by plone.protect 3. I need the entire site, aka all the pages, to be loaded in via iframes for our online tutorial system.

We confirmed our apache is correct because we can load other plone 4 uwosh.edu sites into it.  It is only happening on Plone 5.

I have already looked at:

- https://community.plone.org/t/can-i-configure-my-plone-site-to-be-embedded-via-iframe/2101/4
- https://github.com/plone/plone.protect/issues/36

---

**Our Plone 5 Site:** http://www.uwosh.edu/library

**Broken Tutorial Site which uses iframes:** http://polk2.uwosh.edu/library/gots/tutorial/abiinform-complete

Comment: I needed a "now" temporary fix because a course being taught at the university requires this tutorial system for accreditation.  They are under review next week.  I changed the plone.protect.auto.py x-frame-options to "allow" just to make it through this upcoming week.  I still would like to fix this the right way.

Comment: Not an in-software fix, but since you have Plone behind a reverse proxy anyway, you may be able to unconditionally [unset response headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) there.

Answer (score 2):

The github issue that you referenced has the answer, I believe:  just set the environment variable PLONE_X_FRAME_OPTIONS to an empty string.

You can set this in your zope config file or in buildout, or both:

in buildout, I have:

`environment-vars =
  ...
  PLONE_X_FRAME_OPTIONS ''`

`environment-vars` is used both in `plone.recipe.zeoserver` and in `plone.recipe.zope2instance`.

In your zope conf files:

`<environment>
  ...
  PLONE_X_FRAME_OPTIONS ''
</environment>`